# find the stabilizer of $a$ in $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I am not sure how to find the stabilizer of $a$ in $S_3$, shown my work for previous questions:

> Let $S_3$ act on the set $\Omega$ of ordered pairs: $\{(i,j)\mid 1 \leq i,j\leq 3\}$ by $\sigma((i,j)) = (\sigma(i),\sigma(j)).$
>   Find the orbits of $S_3$ on $\Omega$. For each $\sigma \in S_3$ find the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$ under this action. For each orbit $\mathcal{O}$ of $S_3$ acting on these nine points pick some $a \in \mathcal{O}$ and find the stabilizer of $a$ in $S_3$.

Plugin all elements $s \in S_3$ on $\Omega = \{(i,j)\mid 1 \leq i,j\leq 3\}$ by $\sigma((i,j)) = (\sigma(i),\sigma(j))$ get the orbit:
$$\mathcal{O}^1 = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\},$$
and
$$\mathcal{O}^2 = \{(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)\},$$

Now we consider $\sigma$ under this action and compute its cycle decomposition:
$$\Omega = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)\} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}.$$
\begin{align*}
\sigma_1 = I \in S_3, \sigma_1(\Omega) = \Omega.\\
\sigma_2 = (1, 2)(4, 6)(5,7)(8,9)\\
\sigma_3 = (1, 3)(4, 9)(5,8)(6,7)\\
\sigma_4 = (2,3)(4,5)(6,8)(7,9)\\
\sigma_5 = (1, 2,3)(4,7,8)(5,6,9)\\
\sigma_6 = (1, 3,2)(4,8,7)(5,9,6)\\
\end{align*}

---

**Edit:** Seems "I know" how to do it, but I thought what I did was wrong:

So, according to definition, the stabilizer of $a$ in $G$ is the set of elements of $G$ that fix the element $a$. Therefore:

If we pick $a=(1,1)$, then identity fixes it;

If we pick $a=(2,2)$, both identity and $(1,3)$ fixes it;

If we pick $a = (3,3)$, both identity and $(1,2)$ fixes it;

So these are the stabilizers of $\mathcal{O}^1$ respectively

Is this right...?

Comment: Your solution for $a=(1,1)$ is incomplete. The identity fixes it, and so does $(2,3)$. Like I said, no matter which $a$ you pick, the cardinality of the stabilizer is going to be 2.

Comment: By the way, the problem only asks you to find the stabilizer of one of the elements in each orbit of $S_3$ on $\Omega$, so you don't need to run through all the possible $a$'s as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a result - I've heard it referred to as the "Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem," - which says that if you have an action of $G$ on a set $X$, and $x$ is any element in the orbit $O$, then there is a bijection of sets $G/Stab_{x}G \rightarrow O$. In particular, this allows you to conclude that the stabilizer of any element of $O^{1}$ contains exactly two (= 6 divided by 3) points and the stabilizer of any element of $O^{2}$ contains exactly one (= 6 divided by 6) point. The identity is always in the stabilizer, so the stabilizer of any element of $O^{2}$ must be the trivial subgroup of $S_3$. It remains to find another element which stabilizes, say $(1,1)$  in $O^1$. The permutation $(2 3)$ does the job.

Comment: Thank you Cass. I understand your solution. Thank you so much! However, I have some concern here: according to definition, the stabilizer of $a$ in $G$ is the set of elements of $G$ that fix the element $a$. Therefore, if we pick $a = (1,1)$, then identity fixes it; if we pick $a = (2,2)$, both identity and (1,3) fixes it; and so on.. So where I got wrong?

Comment: You didn't go wrong anywhere. The stabilizer itself (as a subgroup) depends on which element in the orbit you choose to stabilize. What is independent of the chosen element of the orbit is the SIZE of the stabilizer.

Comment: Oh... So I just list the result...? I did for $\mathcal{O}^1$, does it look right...? Thank you Cass.